# Why is my Jupyter notebook running ipython kernel instead of python3? Problem with group bys

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby, jupyter-lab

I've been running into this issue, my Jupyter Lab seems to be running '**Python ipykernel**' instead of just saying running '**python 3**'. Essentially, both of them are python 3 however, I've found a few issues with using ipykernel, I don't know why (Such as simple pandas groupby functions). I didn't feel the need to share any screenshots for this one, hope somebody can help me out; if need be, I can still post it.

I want to make it to Python 3 and not ipykernel

-------- EDIT--------------
Okay, so many of you are  saying that it's not that. I've decided to provide screenshots to show that the outputs of my groupby function are completely different.

EXHIBIT A: Using labs when it just says **Python3**

[image]

EXHIBIT B: Using labs when it just says **Python 3 ipykernel**

[image]

SAME code, SAME dataset, different output ? Why ?

Comment: All jupyter-notebooks use ipython kernel only, you can see it clearly with [IN] and [OUT] and the reason for that is Ipython got support for magic lines & magic cell statements & better support for image displaying & more features than python itself does

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say Jupyter Lab and not Jupyter notebook but essentially, that shouldn't matter. I'm using one which just says Python 3. Have different environments on my terminal. And it's printing out different results for a simple group by function; exact same code and exact same data set :/

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with the kernel, did you try running this on python and see if the output is different? Ipython is python but with better features, both should give the same output, maybe check if you are getting a separate output when you write a py file instead of running an ipynb and get different output. Also groupby is lazy-evaluated, so make sure you are re-writing it in a container data type. The tutorial you may be following could be relevant for old python version as well, it might act different for new python so cross-check that as well

Comment: The issue is absolutely not the kernel. IPython is just a shell that uses the standard Python 3 interpreter

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. I'm not following any tutes, it's a normal CSV data. I'll edit the question again in order for everyone to have a better understanding.

Comment: Screenshots are a good step towards getting it solved but you should also show what is inside the 'new' data frame in both cases and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). My best guess is that the column `Article_Code` differs or is absent the second time you are running the notebook.

Comment: Another likely reason would be a different version of Pandas. You should show which version you used earlier and what is the version you have installed now.

Comment: The data frame remains unchanged, Article_Code still has everything in it! Version of Pandas is also the same. I've resolved the issue by using the one that says Python3 but essentially, it's just weird :/ Thanks for your help either way!

Comment: What do you mean by *using*? Do you have an old copy in another environment, or did you downgrade ipykernel? If what you claim is true then it would hugely benefit the community if you could follow up and produce a reproducible example so that I can investigate and report this as a bug and fix it.

Comment: The same copy is in the Python3 Environment instead of the Python3 ipykernel environment. I didn't downgrade anything. Running it in the one that only mentions Python3, I'll try to re-produce a similar example.

Comment: So *sum* returns a *text*? Sounds like a pandas version difference. Question only valid if you confirm using the same pandas version in both, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

ipykernel **is** using Python 3. Jupyter (whether notebook, lab, or any other interface) **is and always was** using ipykernel as the default kernel for Python. You might be confused because the latest version added the `(ipykernel)` label (in [this PR](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/pull/616)) to inform users which kernel they are using. There are other kernels like xeus-python.

It is **highly**, like **really highly**, unlikely that ipykernel is the source of your problems. You can try downgrading it to previous version if you believe it worked better for you:

```
pip install "ipykernel<6"
```

but actually I would first recommend doing the opposite, this is ensuring that you are running the latest ipykernel patch release with:

```
pip install -U ipykernel
```

Once you confirm that ipykernel is not a source of your problem, I would recommend asking a more detailed question with a reproducible example of the pandas code that you have problem with.

Comment: Hey thanks for trying to answer, however, the problem still remains. I'll edit the question again.

Comment: Does the problem remain after downgrading to older ipykernel version?